# Complexity of swapping Dictionary type arguments in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, group-by, complexity-theory

I have a `Dictionary<A,B>` where objects of `A` are unique and objects of `B` are not.

I want to group the data by objects of `B`.

E.g.

```
Dictionary<A,B> input = GenerateInput();
List<IGrouping<B,A>> output = input
                              .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key)
                              .ToList();
```

1. What is a complexity of the approach? O(n) ? If the complexity = complexity of GroupBy operation - I didn't find the value. Please tell me and provide a link to an article.
2. Is there more efficient/elegant way to do this swapping?

PS. I explicitly write types of variables `input` and `output` to show that I do not need `output` to be of type `Dictioany<,>`. I need a container to go through `A` by `B`.

Comment: GroupBy is an O(n) operation. The mode of operation is very similar to that of creating a Dictionary, where a lookup is made (dictionary-like container that allows multiple values per key), so insertion per element is ~O(1), then enumerated to yield groups.

Answer (score 3):

> What is a complexity of the approach?

Correct, it is O(n). `GroupBy` uses hash codes to group values; assuming that `B` has good hashing function, constructing a table of groups has amortized cost of O(n), which includes amortizing costs of "growing" each group.

> Is there more efficient/elegant way to do this swapping?

O(n) is as efficient as it gets. You can build a dictionary out of the grouping, instead of a list:

```
IDictionary<B,List<A>> output = input
    .GroupBy(pair => pair.Value)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(p.Key).ToList());
```

Comment: ...or an `ILookup<B,A>` which is approximately equivalent to `IDictionary<B,IEnumerable<A>>` with `input.ToLookup(i=>i.Value, i=>i.Key)`.